# how to get data from a model based on another model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have the models tutor, student and subject. both tutor and student have many to many relationship with subject.

i am retrieving the subjects of a tutor with 'subjects' relationship method-

```
$subs = Tutor::find(Auth::user()->id)->subjects()->get();
```

how i can get the students of the same subjects of the tutor. i can display the students in blade, but i need it inside the controller. something like-

```
$students = Students:: where subjects in $subs
```

thanks

Comment: You may have a `$subject->students()` function.

Comment: You can use ```whereHas()``` inside your controller ```Students::whereHas('subject', function ($w){$w->whereIn(col, [])})->get() ```